# SQLite gives negative value on strftime

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database containing dates in the following format: `20190621 22:35:18`. I'm trying to cast this one into DATETIME to further manipulate it.

Thing is, running the following:

```
strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S', my_datetime)
```

Returns `null`

I've tried understanding what's going on, by trying to "breaking" the string into smaller parts. So I've run the following:

```
strftime('%Y', substr(my_datetime, 0, 5))
```

This time, I've got `-470`. (Where I would expect to get `2019`)

Adding month using the same logic returns: `-41609`. (Where I would expect to get `2019-06`)

Adding any additional information returns `null`. So I guess that the problem is the way `strftime` reacts to the year. I have no idea why would SQLite act this way. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: SQLite datetime functions work only with this format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Should `strftime` enable any format?

Comment: `strftime()` is used to format dates/timestamps of the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` to other formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I understood that SQLite only work with the format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

So I've converted the string to the relevant format using:

```
 UPDATE my_table set my_datetime =  substr(my_datetime, 0, 5) || '-' || substr(my_datetime, 5, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(my_datetime, 7, 2) || SUBSTR(my_datetime, 9);
```

And now everything works.